# Regex to exclude text between first occurrence of underline and last occurrence of hyphon

Tags: regex

I am searching for a regex to match

1. the text until (and including) the first occurrence of an underline
   and
2. the text after the last occurrence of a hyphon, but cutting all
   leading zeros

Sample input:

```
Text_un_important-0011
```

Desired result (by concatenting all matches):

```
Text_11
```

I have come up with: `(?:^|(?:00))(.+?)(?:$|_)` but it has some flaws: It works only if there is exactly one hyphen at the end and two leading zeros. Unfortunately I cannot fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow your current logic, you may use

```
^[^_]*_|[1-9]\d*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xeT5M4/2). **Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^_]*` - 0 or more chars other than `_` and then
- `_` - a `_` char
- `|` - or
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits
- `$` - end of string

You may also use a replace logic:

**Find**:       `_.*-0*`
**Replace**: `_`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xeT5M4/1). The `_.*-0*` pattern matches

- `_`  - an underscore
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `-`  - a hyphen
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars.

Since the first `_` is consumed, the replacement pattern should be `_`.

Answer (score 0):

So , you want to capture the first word and the final digits that are not zero:

```
([\w\d]+)(_[\w\d]+)*(-0*)(\d+)
```

use the first and last captured group.

- ([\w\d]+) captures a word that may have a number (ex. word1)
- (_[\w\d]+)* captures repetitions of _word (ex. _word1_anotherword2_third3)
- (-0*) captures a hyphen followed by consecutive zeros (ex. -00000000)
- (\d+) captures all the digits following the consecutive zeros